# Production line probability problem

Tags: probability

> A manufacturer has six distinct motors in stock, two of which came
>   from a particular supplier. The motors must be divided among two
>   production lines, with three motors going to each line. If the
>   assignment of motors to lines is random, find the probability that
>   both motors from the particular supplier are assigned to the first
>   line.

I'd show my attempt but this stumbles me. I don't know what the number of outcomes in which the two from the particular supplier end up on the first line is, for example - nor the total outcomes.

Comment: Hint: For favorable ways, focus on the *second* line, which receives all 3 from same supplier. Once you do this, the other line automatically gets determined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seee total ways of selecting for one of the lines is $${6\choose 3}$$ now we want both same motors in same line so they are fixed its just selecting $1$ from $4$ for last place so there are $4$ ways hence probability is $$\frac{4}{6\choose 3}=4/20=1/5$$

Comment: Your welcome!!...